# force eclipse to use Python 3.5 autocompletion

Tags: python, eclipse, python-3.x, autocomplete

I changed the interpreter for my python projects from 2.x to 3.5 recently. The code interpretes correctly with the 3.5 version.

I noticed that the autocompletion function of Eclipse still autocompletes as if I am using 2.x Python version. For example: `print` gets autocompleted without parenthesis as a statement and not as a function. Any idea how to notify the Eclipse that it need to use 3.5 autocompletion?

Comment: Are you using PyDev? If so, make sure that interpreter grammar is set to 3.0 (`right click project -> Properties -> PyDev - Interpreter/Grammar`)

Comment: thanks! this did the trick. don't forger to post is as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using PyDev, make sure that interpreter grammar is set to 3.0 (`right click project -> Properties -> PyDev - Interpreter/Grammar`)